# unnest_tokens - how to preserve apostrophes at beginning or end of words?

Tags: r, unnest

I am trying to create a corpus with some unusual spellings, and I want to maintain those spellings. For example, if there is an instance of *somethin'*  instead of *something*, I'd like to keep the apostrophe.

Of course, *somethin* is still pretty easy to spot without the apostrophe, but there are also cases like where *and* becomes *an',* but without the apostrophe it is mistaken for *an,* as in *an elephant.* This can be at the beginning or end of words, e.g. *'em* meaning *them* as another example.

Honestly, I have no idea where to even start. Is it possible that there is some kind of regex I could use for this purpose, so I could instruct R to still tokenize by words, but leave apostrophes where they are?

I've just been using this very basic implementation of the code.

```
  df <- df %>%
  unnest_tokens(output = word, 
                input = GV_Text, 
                token = "words")
```

I saw in some other threads some suggestions to use the argument `strip_punct = FALSE`, but then the punctuation is placed in its own row, and I want to preserve it. The reason for this is because I am using OCR on images to extract this text, and I'd like to be able to isolate instances where OCR thinks there is a symbol floating freely, independently of a word (which is unlikely to be the case).

Switching `token = "regex"` does preserve the apostrophes, but it also preserves every other kind of punctuation...

Any help or advice is hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: ok that was easier than I thought. I feel like there is probably another (smarter) way to do this if you know more about regex than I do, but this works for me anyway:

```
df <- df %>%
  unnest_tokens(output = word, 
                input = GV_Text, 
                token = "regex")  #use regex instead of words

word <- as.data.frame(df$word)
word <- gsub("(['])|[[:punct:]]", "\\1", as.matrix(word))
```

Hope this makes sense to anyone who comes across this in the future...